# C# Excel: Find cells using pattern matching

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Is there a way to use the Range.Find() method with numbers-only wildcards or regex?

I'm trying to find cells with values such as "2015 M05", "2016 M08", "2017 M01", to parse the dates in a spreadsheet.

[image]

So far the best I can think of is using the wildcard "?" to form the search string "???? M??"

```
object missingVal = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.Range match = allCells.Find("???? M??", missingVal, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, missingVal, missingVal);
```

However, that will run into problems as soon as I have a two-worded label somewhere having the second word starting with "M".

Edit: I think the simplest thing is if I had some sort of digit-only wildcard that I could use in Range.Find(). However "#" doesn't seem to work so I was wondering if there was some workaround?

Comment: Why don't you define a named table instead and access the table and its header row by name?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll see if it's possible to get that implemented...The thing is I'm writing a C# program that will scrub a folder for spreadsheets. Sometimes the spreadsheets are auto-generated, sometimes they're manually filled out by people. The only consistency I'm guaranteed right now is that the numbers will appear in the row following the dates, so I'm trying to work with what I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `*` in the pattern.  Something like `*?M??` assuming the **M##** pattern is unique.

Comment: Thanks! The #### M## pattern is indeed unique, as in the cell value will always be a 4-digit number (year) followed by a space and "M", followed by a 2-digit number (month).

I'm currently using the search string "???? M??". It works... except when it doesn't. It'll break when I've got an odd entry in the sheet somewhere like "John Moe".

Is there a wildcard for digits only?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. * and ? are the only wildcards in Excel. if that's the case, you're best bet is to pull the values into c# as a object[,] and do some regex.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a shame. Thank you though I think I can make the C# object[,] idea work :)